# Regex help to match groups

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex for matching a text file that has multiple lines such as :

```
* 964      0050.56aa.3480    dynamic   200        F    F  Veth1379
* 930      0025.b52a.dd7e    static    0          F    F  Veth1469
```

My intention is to match the "0050.56aa.3480 " and "Veth1379" and put them in group(1) & group(2) for using later on.

The regex I wrote is :

```
\*\s*\d{1,}\s*(\d{1,}\.(?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)\.\d{1,})\s*(?:[a-z][a-z]+)\s*\d{1,}\s*.\s*.\s*((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))
```

But it does not seem to be working when I test at:
http://www.pythonregex.com/

Could someone point to any obvious error I am doing here.

Thanks,
~Newbie

Comment: pythex.org is more fun, it checks your pattern in real time.

Comment: `(\d{1,}.(?:[a-z][a-z][0-9]+[a-z0-9]).\d{1,})` matches 1+ digits, any character, 2 letters, 1+ digits, 1 alphanumeric, any character, and 1+ digits. This doesn't match `0050.56aa.3480` or `0025.b52a.dd7e`.  Can you define how we match this string?

Comment: A lot of people have issues when they come here asking for regex with only an example. You need to describe the pattern to us in english. If you give us one example and say you need a regex to match it, it can be done with a very simple regex, but probably won't match your other cases, or match too many.

Comment: That is a complicated regex you've got there.

Comment: @aliteralmind: it is because he doesn't use shortcuts `\d{1,}` => `\d+` and `[a-z][a-z]*` => `[a-z]+`, `(?:[a-z][a-z]+)` => `[a-z]{2,}`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I should say "verbose".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\* [0-9]{3} +([0-9]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}).*(Veth[0-9]{4})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vu-7-3AS_Tr9Ixei)

The first part is in capture group one, the "Veth" code in capture group two.

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. There's a list of online testers in the bottom section.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had to editwhat you gave me above but for most part you were correct. This is what I tested thus far and it works. "\*\s*([0-9]{3}\s*[0-9]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}).*(Veth[0-9]{4})$"

Comment: I think you mean `^\*\s*([0-9]{3}\s*[0-9]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}).*(Veth[0-9]{4})$`, but yes, that looks good.

Comment: Hi, I also needed to match lines such as "* 4043     4c00.82f3.95e6    static    0          F    F  Po1309" & "* 4044     a493.4cc7.d559    dynamic   0          F    F  Eth1/1/17" my new regex is "\*\s*[0-9]{1,}\s*([0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}).*([a-z].*)$" but I am having issues in group(2) matching when I test at http://www.pythonregex.com/ could you help me in checking what I am doing wrong. Thanks, Newbie

Comment: Consider asking a new question so you can get fresh help. I can't take a look now as I'm leaving, but I'll check in when I get back. Good luck.

Comment: I finally got it working. As I am newbie here the forum is not allowing me to answer. but here is what I used "\*\s*[0-9]{1,}\s*([0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}).*(Veth\d+|Eth.*|Po\d+)$" Thanks for all the great help

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a regex for this:

```
for line in open('myfile','r').readlines():
    fields = line.split( )
    print "\n" + fields[1] + "\n" +fields[6]
```

Comment: If you pretend that the split function doesn't exist in Python, it makes my regex answer the *obvious* choice.

Answer (score 0):

A *very* strict version would look something like this:

```
^\*\s+\d{3}\s+(\d{4}(?:\.[0-9a-f]{4}){2})\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+\w\s+\w\s+([0-9A-Za-z]+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AokPzOCK8gqXbcm9)

Here I assume that:

- the columns will be pretty much the same,
- your first match group contains a group of decimal digits and two groups of lower-case hex digits,
- and the last word can be anything.

#### A few notes:

- `\d+` is equivalent to `\d{1,}` or `[0-9]{1,}`, but reads better (imo)
- use `\.` to match a literal `.`, as `.` would simply match anything
- `[a-z]{2}` is equivalent to `[a-z][a-z]`, but reads better (my opinion, again)
- however, you might want to use `\w` instead to match a word character

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
reobj = re.compile(r"^.*?([\w]{4}\.[\w]{4}\.[\w]{4}).*?([\w]+)$", re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
match = reobj.search(subject)
if match:
    group1 = match.group(1)
    group2 = match.group(2)
else:
    result = ""
```